# After attempting and failing to convert to PDF, my Word document's formatting was altered. How do I fix this?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf

For a split second upon loading, the document looks like it originally did prior to PDF conversion:

Before it loads:

[image]

Then, it immediately becomes:

[image]

The font sizes are identical, as are the fonts, paragraph breaks, etc.  I don't know what was altered, so I can't just change the font in order to get it back to the state it was in before.

How do I just get it to stay the way looks for the split second before the compiler messes everything up when Word finishes loading?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: Change the view? [Understanding Views (Microsoft Word)](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008142_Understanding_Views.html)

Comment: @DavidPostill First of all, thanks for editing the post.  Secondly, while one of these images looks to be in One Page mode and the other seems to be in Two Page mode, that is not the issue I am facing.  You will see that in the first image, which fits fully to only one page, contains same amount of information as the second, which fits to two pages.  You will also see that lines are wrapping in the second image, meaning the font size was somehow changed.  This should not be happening because Word says the font sizes are the same.

Comment: Most likely your PDF printer had a different page type set and it got pulled back into your document or it got a different set of page margins from the printer. You may have had an A4 page and been printing to a US Letter page. I'd check your [page size settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-paper-size-627c964e-7304-4dac-950c-d7a9a48b5d18)

Comment: Yeah, if lines are wrapping the page width must be different.

Comment: @Mokubai Thank you both for your comments.  However, I just compared the resume template page size against my current document's page size, and they are both 8.5" by 11".  It should be noted the page margins also haven't changed.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Hi guys, I just had some insight.  I am using the same font for the header as the template, but regardless our fonts appear to be very different fonts.  I am thinking it is possible that the template I am using and my own file might be using fonts of the same name, but, despite this, the fonts are being grabbed from different locations.  This may have to do with some internal memory issues.  [See here](https://imgur.com/a/bR4eBNe). Is this plausible?

Comment: If you do not have the same font available on your system then it may be that your are seeing some [font substitution](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/substitute-the-missing-fonts-in-your-publication-b732f59c-210c-41de-a0a4-427535e3e1c7) issue.

Comment: I looked into font substitution, but it wasn't clear to me how I would go about fixing this issue.  Regardless, I got it working by reducing the font size by 1 universally.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is your word doc a table? In the pdf 'Research Assistant' is wrapped.   it looks like the conversion is aligning table columns differently.